# simple inception block in pytorch taking much much longer time to train on GPU?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, conv-neural-network, custom-training

I am training very simple inception block followed by a maxpool and fully-connected layer on NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070 GPU and its taking very long time for an iteration. Just finished 10 iterations in more than 24 hours.

**Here is the code for inception model definition**

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        input_channels = 3
        conv_block = BasicConv2d(input_channels, 64, kernel_size=1)
        self.branch3x3stack = nn.Sequential(
            BasicConv2d(input_channels, 64, kernel_size=1),
            BasicConv2d(64, 96, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            BasicConv2d(96, 96, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
        )

        self.branch3x3 = nn.Sequential(
            BasicConv2d(input_channels, 64, kernel_size=1),
            BasicConv2d(64, 96, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
        )

        self.branch1x1 = BasicConv2d(input_channels, 96, kernel_size=1)

        self.branchpool = nn.Sequential(
            nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            BasicConv2d(input_channels, 96, kernel_size=1),
        )
        self.maxpool = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=8, stride=8)
        self.fc_seqn = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(301056, 1))

    def forward(self, x):
        x = [
            self.branch3x3stack(x),
            self.branch3x3(x),
            self.branch1x1(x),
            self.branchpool(x),
        ]
        x = torch.cat(x, 1)
        x = self.maxpool(x)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        x = self.fc_seqn(x)
        return x  # torch.cat(x, 1)
```

**and the training code I used**

```
def training_code(self, model):
    model = copy.deepcopy(model)
    model = model.to(self.device)
    criterion = nn.MSELoss()
    optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=self.learning_rate)
    for epoch in range(self.epochs):
        print("\n epoch :", epoch)
        running_loss = 0.0
        start_epoch = time.time()
        for i, (inputs, labels) in enumerate(self.train_data_loader):
            inputs = inputs.to(self.device)
            labels = labels.to(self.device)
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            outputs = (model(inputs)).squeeze()
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            running_loss += loss.item()
            if i % log_step == log_step - 1:
                avg_loss = running_loss / float(log_step)
                print("[epoch:%d, batch:%5d] loss: %.3f" % (epoch + 1, i + 1, avg_loss))
                running_loss = 0.0
        if epoch % save_model_step == 0:
            self.path_saved_model = path_saved_model + "_" + str(epoch)
            self.save_model(model)
    print("\nFinished Training\n")
    self.save_model(model)
```

Here is the summary of the convolution neural network. **Can anyone please help me how to speed up the training?**

[image: summary of convolution neural network]

Here is the summary of the convolution neural network after reducing the number of inputs to the fully-connected (FC) layer. But still the training time is very high similar as before. Can suggestion on how to speed up the training will be helpful.

[image: summary of modified cnn]

Comment: What's your batch size? Also `self.fc_seqn = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(301056, 1))` is ridiculously large input size. You should use `torch.nn.AdaptiveMaxPool2d` instead (pooling across channels), which would give you `96` input to `nn.Linear`.

Comment: @SzymonMaszke thanks a lot for the reply. For my case, batch size is 16. other than using pooling across channel is there any other thing I can do to speed up the training process?

Comment: Plethora of things like distributing across many GPUs, using cloud for training etc. It also depends how many data samples you have & what those are (I suppose image, but what's their resolution). Will post an answer, will be easier to go from there.

Answer (score 0):

### Architecture

Your `nn.Linear` has huge input which goes towards only one neuron for regression.

You should use [`torch.nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d.html#torch.nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d) like this:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        ... # your stuff before
        self.pool = nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2D(output_size=1)
        self.fc_seqn = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(96 * 4, 1))

    def forward(self, x):
        x = [
            self.branch3x3stack(x),
            self.branch3x3(x),
            self.branch1x1(x),
            self.branchpool(x),
        ]
        x = torch.cat(x, 1)
        x = torch.squeeze(self.pool(x))
        if len(x.shape) == 1:
            x = torch.unsqueeze(x, dim=0)
        x = self.fc_seqn(x)
        return x
```

It should also help with your task as it won't be as over-parametrized.

### Data

Depending on the size of your image, you may want to crop it (or random crop it) using [`torchvision.transforms`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html) to lower size.

If you can, you could also go with [`torch.nn.DistributedDataParallel`](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/ddp_tutorial.html) in order to parallelize across many GPUs, but I suppose it's not what you are after.

You could also `cache` some data after loading an image (see [`torchdata`](https://szymonmaszke.github.io/torchdata/index.html) project (__disclaimer: I'm the author)).

Also [`torch.utils.data.DataLoader`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader) with `num_workers` argument set to larger number than `1` should speed-up image loading (I usually go with the number of cores my machine has, though you would need some experimentation with it).

### Mixed precision

You should largely benefit from this step as your graphic card supports [Tensor Cores technology](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/data-center/tensor-cores/).

In PyTorch 1.6.0 it's pretty easy with [`torch.cuda.amp`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/amp.html) package. Basically, you just have to use one context manager and gradient scaler ([here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/amp.html#torch.cuda.amp.autocast) and [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/amp.html#gradient-scaling) appropriately).

This allows you to use larger batch size (as architecture has some weight transformed to `float16` instead of `float32`).

Comment: thanks a lot for your helpful suggestions. I have added the nn.AdaptiveMaxPool2d to reduce the input of the FC layer to 384 as u suggested. But still the training time is very high similar as before. I have added the modified cnn architecture to my original post. plz take a look and let me know what possible modifications I can made to remedy this. FYI, for me the num_workers is 4 to load the images during training. Is it possible if I change the framework from pytorch to something else say tensorflow then training will be faster for inception block. any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: Try mixed precision before changing framework. This should help a lot.

Comment: can u plz share some links on training using mixed precision?

Comment: You have them in my answer, last paragraph and there's plethora of examples online as well, check them docs.